# file_put_contents not working one place, but working elsewhere in code

Tags: php

Im new to PHP, but used to Java. 
I have a file, dd-functions.php that contains a function (writeToLog).
This function will create a variable with the log-statement, then write it to a file.

The strange thing is that this works perfectly when it is called from one php-file (file1.php), but when called from another php-file (file2.php), it does not write anything to the file.
In both file1.php and file2.php, the functions.php is included once.

How is this even possible?

Function.php

```
/* Log for user */
function writeToLog($user, $analyseName, $remaining_downloads) {

$uid = $user->ID;

$userdata = get_userdata($uid);
if ($userdata->first_name) {
    $username = $userdata->first_name . ' ' . $userdata->last_name;
} else {
    $username = $userdata->user_login;
}
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Oslo');
$date = date('d.m.Y H:i:s');
$s2member_access_level = get_user_field ("s2member_access_level", $uid);
$userLog = $uid . "\t" . $date . "\t" . $username . "\t" . $user->user_email . "\t" . $analyseName . "\t" . $remaining_downloads . "\t" . $s2member_access_level . "\n";

file_put_contents('analyse-email-click-log.txt', $userLog , FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: What's get_userdata ? and get_user_field ?

Comment: Wordpress and S2 member functions that retrieves some user data.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the file with a hierarchy or you only have to include this file with the include statement.

**Hierarchy**

```
<?php

    class ClassA extends ClassB {


    }
```

**Include**

```
log.php
<?php

$logA = 'mylogA';
$logB = 'otherlog';

?>

test.php
<?php


include 'log.php';

echo "Show my $logA"; 

?>
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand what you mean? Both places that use this function include the functions file by: require_once('dd_functions.php');

Answer (score 0):

This **may be** because of your relative path to `analyse-email-click-log.txt`.

If you have three php files like this

```
/lib.php
/foo.php
/sub/bar.php
```

Let  `writeToLog` reside in lib.php and include the `/lib.php` file from `/foo.php` and `/sub/bar.php`. If you run `/foo.php`, it will write to `/analyse-email-click-log.txt` but if you run `/sub/bar.php` it will write to `/sub/analyse-email-click-log.txt`, which may be protected by write permissions.

Comment: Good idea. But unfortunatly all three files are in the same directory.